# Is it possible to change app display name without changing module name?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm wanting to change app display name for my iOS Project on XCode. The problem is that once I change `PRODUCT NAME` on build settings, I start getting hundred of linking errors on test project. It doesn't find classes anymore

On all test clasess I had `import MyAppOldName` and I was forced to change it to `import MyAppNewName`. Even after this change, linker errors persist.

I just want to change the display name, don't want to struggle with XCode for 2 hours just because of this.

Comment: It depends where you change it.  A number of configuration values rely on the value of other configuration values.  Examine the *Build Settings* to find out how they work.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I only want to change the display name, not sure why this breaks the test project. If there is a better and simpler way to do it, I'd go for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xcode, select your target. Then select the "Info" tab. Find the "Bundle display name" key. Most likely its current value is `${PRODUCT_NAME}`. Simply replace that value with the text of the name you wish to appear under the app icon.

If there is no "Bundle display name" entry, add a new key and select "Bundle display name" from the dropdown list.

This change will have no other effect other than changing the name under the icon.

Comment: `Bundle display name` doesn't  exist. I'll create it and see how it goes

Comment: I think it's been renamed to `Bundle name`.